# How to remove certain html elements from the html content retrieved dynamically using file_get_html and str_get_html in php?

Tags: php, html, cakephp

I am trying to create an email template from existing html page where I am fetching content direct from html page and sending it via email. But the problem is I am getting certain buttons that I need to remove. Below is my code:

```
function HtmltoPhp_url($id=null)
    {
        App::import('Vendor', 'simple_html_dom');
        if($id!=null){
            $html = file_get_html('https://forexsense.in/members/order_progress/'.$id);
            foreach($html->find('.dtls') as $elem)
            return  str_get_html($elem);
        }
     
    }
```

Below is my code to set email content in cakephp:

```
 $email->viewVars(
                array(
                        'emailContent' => $this->phptopdf_url($order['ForexOrder']['id'])
                     )
            );
```

I am getting below output from below link:
https://forexsense.in/members/order_progress/17

I want to remove Buttons from  here in email content. Please assist!

Comment: you could convert your html to string and str_replace() the button for blank string. But Isnt it easier to add a template specifically for it? You will find alot of html and css is going to appear much different in a email client than  it does in a web browser. specific email template could be better

Comment: seems good to be implemented.. let me try str_replace ;) thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could convert your html to string and `str_replace()` the button for blank string like this:

```
$removedButton = str_replace('<a href="/location">myButton</a>', '', $htmlString);
```

Now your buttons should be removed.

Comment: though your comment already helped me... yet I am accepting your answer :D thanks anyways!!